# this.variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, dojo

Hi there I am getting the error this._radioButtons is undefined ( the code between **)in the following snippet. Is there something about the closures that I am missing here?

```
_adjustChoices: function(choices) {
            // TODO Tear down all the old radion buttons and their change handlers.
            debugger;
            this._radioButtons = [];
            this._changeHandlers = [];
            array.forEach(choices, function(choice) {
                var radioButton = new RadioButton(lang.mixin({
                    name: this._clusterName
                }, choice));
                **this._radioButtons.push(radioButton);**
                this._changeHandlers.push(connect.connect, radioButton, "onChange", lang.hitch(this, function(value) {
                    // TODO Figure out which radio button is selected and get its value.
                    //var radioButton = ????;
                    this.set("value", radioButton.get("checked"));
                }));
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inside `array.forEach(choices, function(choice) { /* your code here*/ })` callback function and therefore `this` refers to the function. Add `this` as a 3rd argument to force context:

```
array.forEach(choices, function(choice) { 

    // YOUR CODE HERE

}, this);  // => here
```

Answer (score 0):

In my personal opinion, readability can be improved by declaring some kind of pointer outside the buggy function-scope like

```
// code code code
_adjustChoices: function(choices) {
    var _this = this;
    // rest of your code...

    array.forEach(choices, function(choice) {
        //stuff you do
        var radioButton = new RadioButton(lang.mixin({
                name: _this._clusterName                //access it this way
            }, choice));
    }
}
```

That way, it is possible to acces each `this`-pointer and even naming it like `this_adustChoices` or whatnot...